# What would cause a user's activation link to fail?

Tags: users, activation

I've just rolled out some changes to a site that's now seeing a big increase in (front end) user sign ups.

I have activation by email on and I'm tracking in analytics the number of hits to the activation success and activation failed pages.

If I look at yesterday as an example, 168 Success and 15 Failed.

I'd like to start working on bringing this down, but it would be useful to know the scenarios that would cause a user to hit the failed page. I believe they'll get this if they, for example, click the activation email twice.

Is there any other obvious causes that I use as a starting point?

Thanks!

Comment: We've had issues before where the activation link truncates for some people because it is too long and therefore, that link is broken.

Comment: Yep I've had that! Not so much since moving to Craft but had it a lot with EE.

Answer (score 2):

1. They could already be active Users
2. Their activation link could have timed out

1) happens more often than I'd think, people try using it as a way of "getting to the site again"

2) Can be controlled in /config/general.php - https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#verificationCodeDuration

Comment: That's great. Didn't know there was the setting for the time. Think I might bump it up slightly and then include in the activation email that the link is only valid for X days.

Comment: Is it possible to include a trigger for the user to resend an activation from the front end? I know I can do it from the CP, but would be good if the user can request it.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, unfortunately.